Web Server in C++: Threaded
Planning on writing a set of blog articles on how to write a webs server.
So each phase will have a new version of the server with extra features. But starting very basic and working up to a reasonable (not apache good) server written in C++ that people can take and play with.
Before I go and show the code in an article I hope I can get some feedback here to make sure I don't do anything to stupid.
Version 2: Help From Threads
This version uses threads:
The main thread handles accepting new connections.
Any child threads will then be used to processes the request in the background.
This will prevent a hard to render page from blocking new connections. With more threads you can processes multiple pages simultaneously. But because the streams are blocking you can still run out of connections.
  #include <ThorsSocket/Server.h>
  #include <ThorsSocket/Socket.h>
  #include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>
  #include <ThorsLogging/ThorsLogging.h>
  #include <charconv>
  #include <vector>
  #include <thread>
  #include <mutex>
  #include <condition_variable>
  #include <iostream>


  using Connections = std::queue<ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream>;
  std::vector<std::thread>    workers;
  std::mutex                  connectionMutex;
  std::condition_variable     connectionCV;
  Connections                 connections;

  void connectionHandler();

  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
      loguru::g_stderr_verbosity = 9;

      std::cerr << PACKAGE_STRING << " Server\n";

      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Server;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Socket;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::CertificateInfo;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLMethodType;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLctx;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::ServerInfo;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SServerInfo;
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Blocking;

      int port = 8080;
      if (argc > 1) {
          port = std::stoi(argv[1]);
      }

  #define EXAMPLE_CERTIFICATE_INFO    "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/"

  #ifdef CERTIFICATE_INFO
      // If you have site certificate set CERTIFICATE_INFO to the path
      // This will then create an HTTPS server.
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::CertificateInfo;
      CertificateInfo certificate{CERTIFICATE_INFO "fullchain.pem",
                                  CERTIFICATE_INFO "privkey.pem"
                                 };
      SSLctx          ctx{SSLMethodType::Server, certificate};
      Server          server{SServerInfo{port, ctx}};
  #else
      // Without a site certificate you should only use an HTTP port.
      // But most modern browsers are going to complain.
      // See: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/
      //      On how to get a free signed site certificate.
      Server          server{ServerInfo{port}};
  #endif

      workers.emplace_back(connectionHandler);

      while (true)
      {
          Socket          accept = server.accept(Blocking::No);
          std::unique_lock    lock(connectionMutex);
          connections.emplace(std::move(accept));
          connectionCV.notify_one();
      }
  }

  ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream getNextStream()
  {
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;

      std::unique_lock    lock(connectionMutex);
      connectionCV.wait(lock, [](){return !connections.empty();});
      SocketStream socket = std::move(connections.front());
      connections.pop();
      return socket;
  }

  void connectionHandler()
  {
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;

      while (true)
      {
          SocketStream stream = getNextStream();

          for (bool closeSocket = false; !closeSocket && stream.good();)
          {
              closeSocket = true;
              std::size_t bodySize = 0;
              std::string line;
              while (std::getline(stream, line))
              {
                  std::cout << "Request: " << line << "\n";
                  if (line == "\r") {
                      break;
                  }
                  if (line == "Connection: keep-alive\r") {
                      closeSocket = false;
                  }
                  if (line.compare("Content-Length: ") == 0) {
                      std::from_chars(&line[0] + 16, &line[0] + line.size(), bodySize);
                  }
              }
              stream.ignore(bodySize);

              if (stream)
              {
                  stream << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                         << "Content-Length: 135\r\n"
                         << "\r\n"
                         << R"(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html>
  <head><title>Nissa server 1.1</title></head>
  <body>Hello World</body>
  </html>)";
                  stream.flush();
              }
          }
      }

Note: I am using some basic streaming library that I have written and previously had code reviewed "ThorsSocket". It is available on GitHub but easier to download via brew.
Link with: -lThorsSocket -lThorsLogging

In addition to everything that came up in a related review…:
#include <ThorsSocket/Server.h>
#include <ThorsSocket/Socket.h>
#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>
#include <ThorsLogging/ThorsLogging.h>
#include <charconv>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

Because includes can interfere with each other, it is generally wise to order them consistently and logically. Normally that means grouping by library, then alphabetically.
Also, is the logging library really necessary?
using Connections = std::queue<ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream>;
// ...
std::mutex                  connectionMutex;
std::condition_variable     connectionCV;
Connections                 connections;

Using global variables is always poor form, and not even necessary. I know tutorial code has to take shortcuts and do simplifications, but I don’t agree that that’s an excuse to use poor practices. Even with shortcuts and simplifications, tutorials should still demonstrate good practices.
Put yourself in the shoes of a beginner who wants to use your tutorial as a starting point for their own project. Rather than starting with a solid framework, right off the bat they’ve been hamstrung. Either they stick with the foundation and end up with poorly-structured code, or they’re forced to struggle on their own to figure out how to fix it.
Granted, the following structure is slightly more complex, but not by much, and it shows the reader what good code—albeit simplified and stripped down—is supposed to look like:
void connectionHandler(std::queue<ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream>&);

auto main() -> int
{
    // ...

    auto connections = std::queue<ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream>{};

    auto workers = std::vector<std::thread>(/*number of threads*/);
    std::ranges::for_each(workers, [&connections](auto&& worker) { worker = std::thread{&connectionHandler, std::ref(connections)}; });

    while (true)
    {
        connections.emplace(server.accept(Blocking::No));
    }
}

void connectionHandler(std::queue<ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream>& connections)
{
    while (true)
    {
        auto socket = connections.pop();

        // ...
    }
}

Plus, it demonstrates things that a reader may not necessarily know, like that you can send parameters to a thread functions, and you should use std::ref() if they’re references. Tutorials very often teach things that are technically outside the purview of the tutorial, just by demonstrating good code.
Back to the variables:
using Connections = std::queue<ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream>;
// ...
std::mutex                  connectionMutex;
std::condition_variable     connectionCV;
Connections                 connections;

I’m not sure the type alias really serves any purpose. After all, there is only one place the type ever appears. Even if it appears multiple times, using aliases in tutorial code is probably not a good idea. They can often be more obscuring than revealing.
Also, I know the intention is to “class-ify” the code later, and that there will be a proper concurrent queue at that time, but still, I don’t think raw-dogging a concurrent queue like this is demonstrating good practice. And it just complicates the business logic. Just compare this:
  ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream getNextStream()
  {
      using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;

      std::unique_lock    lock(connectionMutex);
      connectionCV.wait(lock, [](){return !connections.empty();});
      SocketStream socket = std::move(connections.front());
      connections.pop();
      return socket;
  }

… to this:
  ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream getNextStream()
  {
      return connections.pop();
  }

It doesn’t need to be a quality concurrent queue class. Frankly I wouldn’t even bother with the condition variable. I’d just do something like:
template<typename T>
class concurrent_queue
{
public:
    auto push(T value)
    {
        if (_closed.load())
            throw std::logic_error{"queue is closed"};

        auto lock = std::scoped_lock{_mutex};
        _queue.push(std::move(value));
    }

    auto pop()
    {
        auto result = std::optional<T>{};
        if (_closed.load())
            return result;

        auto lock = std::unique_lock{_mutex};
        while (_queue.empty() and not _closed.load())
        {
            lock.unlock();
            std::this_thread::yield();
            lock.lock();
        }

        if (not _queue.empty())
        {
            result.emplace(std::move(_queue.front()));
            _queue.pop();
        }

        return result;
    }

    auto close() noexcept
    {
        _closed = true;
    }

    auto is_closed() const noexcept
    {
        return _closed.load();
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> _queue;
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::atomic<bool> _closed;
};

That’ll do for a start. Understanding this shouldn’t tax the reader too much; they don’t need to know about condition variables, or any of the complexity they bring. The pop() function is a little long, but not hard to understand. The reader can then more or less replace it with a proper concurrent queue at their leisure, or improve this class if they prefer.
The most important thing about it, other than demonstrating good practices, is that it massively simplifies the important parts of the code.
One last thing about those global variables:
  std::vector<std::thread>    workers;

New C++ code should use std::jthread, not std::thread. std::jthread is what std::thread should have been. It is superior in every way, with no drawbacks.
And while you’re using std::jthread, you should demonstrate co-operative cancellation. Yes, it adds a little complexity, but not all that much. But it demonstrates best practices, and, by-the-by, fixes or prevents bugs.
Speaking of….
I understand that with tutorial code, one generally doesn’t want to include error-handling code. Nevertheless, one should at least be cognizant of where errors can happen, and where they can cause problems.
Let’s start with connectionHandler(). If any exceptions get thrown while handling a request, it will terminate the entire server. At the very least, thread functions should always look like:
auto thread_function()
{
    try
    {
        // Actual code.
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // Log/report/whatever errors.
    }
}

You don’t even need to waste verbiage in the tutorial explaining that; it should just be C++ threading 101. Since your thread function is effectively doing tasks in a loop, it should actually be:
auto thread_function()
{
    try
    {
        while (not done)
        {
            // Get next task.

            try
            {
                // Do task.
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                // Log/report/whatever errors with the task.
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // Log/report/whatever errors.
    }
}

But if the “get next task” bit cannot fail, which is not unreasonable for a concurrent queue popping-moving socket streams, you can ditch the outer try.
We’ll get back to the thread function, but there is a much more serious issue to fix first.
After you create and launch your processing threads, you start the main thread loop:
      while (true)
      {
          Socket          accept = server.accept(Blocking::No);
          std::unique_lock    lock(connectionMutex);
          connections.emplace(std::move(accept));
          connectionCV.notify_one();
      }

So the concurrency stuff does not throw, and I don’t know if any of the socket stuff throws… but I know for a fact that pushing/emplacing onto a std::queue can definitely throw.
If it does, consider what happens. The stack in main() starts unwinding… which starts destroying the vector of worker threads… which are presumably still joinable… which means: crash. Any requests currently being processed are abruptly choked off, perhaps even after starting to send a response, which, from the perspective of the client, just leaves them hanging.
All in all, it’s hardly an orderly exit.
So the first step to fixing this is to just use std::jthread. That should have been the default in any case; never use std::thread in C++20 or  beyond.
Now when main() starts unwinding and tries destroying the worker threads, they don’t just… explode… they make a stop request, and then wait to join.
Which brings us back to the worker thread function. Above I just used “not done” in the thread function… but it should be “not stop_token.stop_requested()”. As in:
void connectionHandler(
    std::stop_token stop_token,
    concurrent_queue<ThorsSocket::Socket>& connection_queue
)
{
    while (not stop_token.stop_requested() and not connection_queue.is_closed())
    {
        try
        {
            if (auto socket = connection_queue.pop(); socket)
            {
                auto stream = ThorsSocket::SocketStream{*socket};

                // ... etc.
                //
                // If you want, you can check stop_token for more fine-grained
                // cancellation control.
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // Ignore errors.
        }
    }
}

Now, no matter what happens, the worker thread will cleanly finish handling the request (or bail early if you choose).
So, here is the code structure from the non-threaded version review:
auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    auto const options = parse_options(argc, argv);

    auto server = initialize_server(options);

    while (server.is_accepting_connections())
    {
        auto connection = accept_connection(server);
        auto stream = ThorsSocket::SocketStream{std::move(connection)};

        while (stream)
        {
            auto request = parse_request(stream);
            handle_request(request, stream):
        }
    }
}

That should really have been wrapped in a try block… indeed, main() should always be like that:
auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    try
    {
        auto const options = parse_options(argc, argv);

        auto server = initialize_server(options);

        while (server.is_accepting_connections())
        {
            auto connection = accept_connection(server);
            auto stream = ThorsSocket::SocketStream{std::move(connection)};

            while (stream)
            {
                auto request = parse_request(stream);
                handle_request(request, stream):
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // Ignore errors.
    }
}

Now to thread-ify it:
auto handle_connection(
    std::stop_token stop_token,
    concurrent_queue<ThorsSocket::Socket>& connection_queue
)
{
    while (not stop_token.stop_requested() and not connection_queue.is_closed())
    {
        try
        {
            if (auto socket = connection_queue.pop(); socket)
            {
                auto stream = ThorsSocket::SocketStream{std::move(*socket)};

                while (stream)
                {
                    auto request = parse_request(stream);
                    handle_request(request, stream):
                }
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // Ignore errors.
        }
    }
}

auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    try
    {
        auto const options = parse_options(argc, argv);

        auto server = initialize_server(options);

        auto connection_queue = concurrent_queue<ThorsSocket::Socket>{};

        auto workers = std::vector<std::jthread>(options.number_of_connection_threads);
        std::ranges::for_each(workers, [&connection_queue](auto&& worker)
        {
            worker = std::jthread{&handle_connection, std::ref(connection_queue)};
        });

        while (server.is_accepting_connections())
        {
            connection_queue.push(accept_connection(server));
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // Ignore errors.
    }
}

Which is a pretty simple and logical extension of the non-thread code. You just add the lines constructing the worker threads and connection queue to main(), and then move the body of the main loop to the thread function. Most of the extra lines are just the standard scaffolding for any thread function.
You will need the extra concurrent queue class, but again, that doesn’t need to be complex (and it could be dumped into an include file so it doesn’t clutter up the main server code). That’s about the only extra code you will need going from single-threaded to multi-threaded.

includes .... order them consistently and logically: I have a grouping order. But I think yout point is I should make that obvious. My Order is:  1: The header file for this file. 2: Any header files from this project. 3: Any library header files. (sub grouped together by library) 4: Standard C++ header. 5: Standard C header. i.e. Most specific to least specific.

Even with shortcuts and simplifications, tutorials should still demonstrate good practices. Yes. Don't introduce bad habits.

I think I need a question specifically on the work queue. I prefer my version and thing it is easier to understand that your version. But that is the point of having a question to get a beter version.

OK. I need to read up on std::jthread I have heard about them but not on the benifits (just that they auto join on destruction).

Never seen std::stop_token. Do you have reference for this and std::jthreads. I need to do some more reading.

I have rereading you concurrent_queue looks just like you are manually implementing the condition variable.

Yes, the condition variable is definitely more efficient, too, in the long run. It just brings so much complexity with it. Like you either have to explain why you should unlock the mutex before notifying, or hand-wave past it. Manually loop-yielding a mutex is less efficient, but much simpler to understand. (And it can be left to the reader to improve it later.)

Think I have it now: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/294091/c-webserver-jobqueue-part-2

I have quoted you here. https://lokiastari.com/posts/NisseV4
If you don't want me to link to your SO bio let me know.

@LokiAstari It’s no problem! (Sorry for the long delay in replying; I’ve been extremely sick.)
