C++ WebServer: JobQueue Part-2
I think I made a mistake trying to start from the simplest version and working forward. This time I will present the final version, get all the fixes from here and incorperat them into the code, then I can reverse engineer the steps to get there.
The Parts of the server are:

NisseServer: Part-5
EventHandler: Part-4
Store: Part-3
JobQueue: Part-2
Pynt: Part-1

This post deals only with JobQueue.
I know I should use std::jthread. Unfortunately Apples C++ compiler currently does not support std::jthread yet.
JobQueue.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_JOB_QUEUE_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_JOB_QUEUE_H

/*
 * The class that holds all the background threads and work that the threads will do.
 *
 * Constructor creates all the child threads.
 * New jobs added via `addJob()` which will then be executed ASAP by one of the threads.
 */

#include "NisseConfig.h"
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <optional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse
{

using Work    = std::function<void()>;
class JobQueue
{
    std::vector<std::thread>        workers;
    std::mutex                      workMutex;
    std::condition_variable         workCV;
    std::queue<Work>                workQueue;
    bool                            finished;

    public:
        JobQueue(int workerCount);
        ~JobQueue();

        void addJob(Work&& action);
        void stop();

    private:
        std::optional<Work> getNextJob();
        void                processWork();
        void                markFinished();
};

}

#endif

JobQueue.cpp
#include "JobQueue.h"
#include <ThorsLogging/ThorsLogging.h>

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse;

JobQueue::JobQueue(int workerCount)
    : finished(false)
{
    try
    {
        for (int loop = 0; loop < workerCount; ++loop) {
            workers.emplace_back(&JobQueue::processWork, this);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stop();
        throw;
    }
}

JobQueue::~JobQueue()
{
    stop();
}

void JobQueue::addJob(Work&& action)
{
    std::unique_lock    lock(workMutex);
    workQueue.emplace(action);
    workCV.notify_one();
}

void JobQueue::markFinished()
{
    std::unique_lock    lock(workMutex);
    finished = true;
}

void JobQueue::stop()
{
    markFinished();
    workCV.notify_all();
    for (auto& w: workers) {
        w.join();
    }
    workers.clear();
}

std::optional<Work> JobQueue::getNextJob()
{
    std::unique_lock    lock(workMutex);
    workCV.wait(lock, [&](){return !workQueue.empty() || finished;});

    if (workQueue.empty() || finished) {
        return {};
    }


    Work work = std::move(workQueue.front());
    workQueue.pop();
    return work;
}

void JobQueue::processWork()
{
    while (!finished)
    {
        std::optional<Work> work   = getNextJob();
        try
        {
            if (work.has_value()) {
                (*work)();
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception const& e)
        {
            ThorsLogWarning("ThorsAnvil::Nissa::JobQueue::", "processWork", "Work Exception: ",  e.what());
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            ThorsLogWarning("ThorsAnvil::Nissa::JobQueue::", "processWork", "Work Exception: Unknown");
        }
    }
}

